# AngularJs : When does the controller get executed

Tags: angularjs

In case of angular, in its life cycle when does the controller that we define using the .controller method get executed?

Answer (score 1):

**First**, when you are **accessing** a **DOM** with **ng-controller** attached to it.


**E.g.**

```
<ul ng-controller="YourCtrl">
   <li ng-repeat="name in names">
       {{name.firstName}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Documentation:** https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller



**Second**, when you are **accessing** a **URL route** using **$routeProvider / $stateProvider** that has the method **when() / state()** with the parameter **controller**.


**E.g.**


**Using ngRoute:**

```
$routeProvider
     .when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'app/views/home.html',
         controller: 'homeCtrl'
     })
     .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
     });
```

**Using ui.router:**

```
$stateProvider
     .state('home', {
       url: '/home',
       templateUrl: 'partial-home.html',
       controller: 'homeCtrl'
     });
```

Hope it helps.